# Object coords not updated when exporting/importing

Tags: python, export, coordinates

I'm new to Blender and have a face model with scale of 1. Exported the blender model as STL file which matches the Blender model. Exported the coordinates and plotted them in Python which measures as in Blender.

Now, in Blender, I changed the scale to 0.15 in XYZ. Exported the model to STL file which matches the scaled down version. Exported the coordinates and to my surprise, the coordinates are the same as before. Am I missing something? Why didn't the coordinates scale down?

Comment: Without testing sounds like a local coordinates are exported.  Eg one corner of default cube has local vertex coordinate (1, 1, 1)  If the cube is scaled 4x the local coordinate is same (1, 1, 1) but appears at (4, 4, 4).  If scale is applied to object in blender Ctrl-A scale , the scale becomes 1 (unity), the local coordinate of corner vertex is changed to (4, 4, 4).

Comment: Perfect. That solved it. Thank you.